# Как устранить утечку памяти при работе с односвязным списком

Tags: c, память, malloc, valgrind

Valgrind пишет, что у меня полностью потеряны блоки, которые выделяются в функции `ft_print_recursion`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я неправильно освобождаю?

```
typedef struct      s_flist
{
    char            *name;
    char            *path;
    struct s_flist  *next;
}                   t_flist;

void    print_recursion(char *path, t_opt options)  
{  
    t_flist     *new_head;

    new_head = (t_flist*)malloc(sizeof(t_flist));
    if (! new_head)
    {
        perror("cannot allocate memory");
        exit(1);
    }
    ft_read_dir(path, options, &new_head);
    new_head = ft_sort_flist(options, new_head);
    ft_print_flist(options, new_head);
    ft_delete_flist(&new_head);
    free(new_head);
}

void        ft_clean_flist(t_flist **file)
{
    ft_strdel(&(*file)->name);
    ft_strdel(&(*file)->path);
}

void        ft_delete_flist(t_flist **head)
{
    t_flist     *tmp;

    while (*head)
    {
        tmp = (*head);
        (*head) = (*head)->next;
        ft_clean_flist(&tmp);
        free(tmp);
    }
     if (*head)
    {
        ft_clean_flist(head);
        free(head);
    }  
}
```

в процессе список заполняется функцией:

```
void        ft_push_fname(t_flist **head, char *path)
{

t_flist *tmp = NULL;

tmp = (t_flist*)malloc(sizeof(t_flist));
if (!tmp)
{
    perror("cannot allocate memory");
    exit(1);
}
tmp->path = ft_strdup(path);
tmp->name = cut_name(path);
tmp->next = (*head);
(*head) = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот суть вашего кода:

```
new_head = (t_flist*)malloc(sizeof(t_flist));
...
new_head = ft_sort_flist(options, new_head);
...
free(new_head);
```

Посмотрите - какую именно память вы освобождаете при вызове `free`? Не теряете ли вы указатель на какую-то память?

Дальше намекать? :)

Comment: Да, если можно. Мне кажется, что я создаю новый список, к нему добавляются новые элементы, потом я их сортирую, печатаю, а дальше пропускаю весь список через удаление и в конце освобождаю то, что создала в самом начале

Comment: Вы выделили память в первой строке (в моем ответе). Записали в переменную ее адрес. Затем перезаписали переменную, навсегда потеряв адрес блока памяти. Освобождаете вы уже не первый выделенный блок, а второй. А первый - все... он потерян - к нему никак нельзя обратиться: его адрес не сохранился. Вот и все, утечка памяти...

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Все так просто, но я в упор этого не видела